# ko click reference error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i've a problem with click event on KnockoutJS. 
When I click the icon that should call the function to open the pop-up, or rather when I load the page I get the following error

```
 knockout-3.2.0.js:63 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return showOfferDetails }"
Message: showOfferDetails is not defined
```

i call this function in:

```
<div title="<spring:message code="frontendResources.Details" />" class="btn-bar btn-details" data-bind="click: showOfferDetails"></div>
```

The js code of the ViewModel  is:

```
(function(viewModels) {
var viewModel = function(offerID) {
    var self = this;

    this.pageStates = {
        view: 0,
        showDetails: 2
    };

    this.showOfferDetails = ko.observable(null);

    this.pageState = ko.observable(this.pageStates.view);
    this.offerCredit = ko.observable(null);
    this.currentItemToShow = ko.observable(null);
    this.hasResults = ko.observable(true);
    this.tabViewModel = new TabViewModel();

    this.loadData = function () {
        backoffice.viewModels.ajaxOverlay.showLoader();
        self.showOfferDetails();

    };

    this.showOfferDetails  = function () {
        backoffice.viewModels.ajaxOverlay.showLoader();

        self.pageState(self.pageStates.showDetails);

        backoffice.viewModels.ajaxOverlay.hide();
    };


    this.hideDetails = function () {
        self.currentItemToShow(null);
        self.pageState(self.pageStates.view);
    }

    this.detailsIsVisible = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.pageState() == self.pageStates.showDetails;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            if (value) {
                self.showOfferDetails();
            } else {
                self.hideDetails();
            }
        }
    });


    this.loadData();
};

    viewModels.offerCredit = viewModel;
})( backoffice.viewModels );
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is this meant for ? - this.showOfferDetails = ko.observable(null);

Comment: is irrelevant had put them to understand the problem but even without it does not work

Comment: It means that there's no `showOfferDetails` property in your current binding context. Are you inside a `with` or `foreach` binding? Here's how you can log the element's binding context: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/knockout.js/5066/debugging-a-knockout-js-application#t=201610241038274760762

Comment: no, i am not inside a with or foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At viewmodel construction you keep a reference to this in the self variable:

```
var self = this;
```

but you're not using this self variable for all of the viewmodel's observables or functions. Instead they are assigned to the possibly changing `this` reference leading to the "is not defined" error message.

Try setting the observables and functions to the self variable:

```
self.showOfferDetails  = function () {
    backoffice.viewModels.ajaxOverlay.showLoader();
    self.pageState(self.pageStates.showDetails);
    backoffice.viewModels.ajaxOverlay.hide();
};
```